# Comparing looped value to list

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I am comparing a value pulled from a search cursor to a list using the statement:

```
 if value in longlist:
```

I need it to return which index matches in longlist.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In python, the easiest way would probably be:

```
a_list = [ 'foo', 'bar' , 'foo']
a_list.index('foo')
```

Alternatively, if it is possible that the element is found several times in the `longlist`, you can use `map`:

```
map(lambda x:x=='foo',a_list)
```

Which will return in this case:

```
[True, False, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Python, you're looking for `longlist.index(value)`:

```
In [13]: [1, 2, 3].index(2)
Out[13]: 1
```

Note that this raises a `ValueError` if the item is not in the list.